# how to select 2 tables data using single query in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am working on Library Management and for making a report I want to get data from 2 tables which are not interlinked i.e `issueData` and `issueRecord`.

The Record contains previous book issued data while the Data table contains only the current book issued Report.

Simply, I want to merge these two queries i.e

1. `Select * From issueRecord where issueDate = '19/07/2013'`.
2. `Select * From issueData where issueDate = '19/07/2013'`.

Please Help.

Comment: cant you simply use UNION ALL?

Comment: Use [Joins](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Comment: And of course select * is a SQL antipattern and should not be used in production code. BUt to really help you, we need to know the table structure of those two tables.

Comment: @Appyks -- you're assuming the tables have the same columns which is the only way UNION ALL would work.  Vedant -- you're assuming there is a condition to join on.  It appears to me the OP was simply asking how to get both sets of data to show up in the same report, not necessarily in the same result set.

Comment: Sorry to all those who think my question is not clear but I got my answer from the first comment. Thanks to all of those who viewed my post and tried to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question was more clear we would be able to help more.

From what I understand you are trying for a union all or union. There is also a chance for cross join also, but that may not be the result you wanted.

There are answers for Union and union all, But I would suggest you to use like the below

```
Select 'Record', Field_1, Field_2, Field_3 From issueRecord where issueDate = '19/07/2013'
UNION
Select 'Data', Field_A, Field_B, Field_C From issueData where issueDate = '19/07/2013'
```

With this addition you can find which data is from which table.

In addition to this you can also use cross join

```
select * from issueRecord  CROSS JOIN issueData
```

but check the data what you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but it seems like you are looking for a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` query.

Assuming that what you want is a single result set that includes record from each table, but you are not trying to combine the two tables onto a single line, the syntax would be something along the lines of:

```
Select Field_1, Field_2, Field_3 From issueRecord where issueDate = '19/07/2013'
UNION
Select Field_A, Field_B, Field_C From issueData where issueDate = '19/07/2013'
```

The type and order of the columns selected from both tables have to match.  `UNION` will collapse identical records into one output row, just like a distinct clause, while `UNION ALL` will include every record from each query.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but there was a more clear and appropriate answer from @vinbhai4u